# Filter React Components via search bar using onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, onchange, react-component

I have a react app with multiple components rendered on several different pages.
I built a search bar component, to be re-used and rendered on 5 different pages,
to filter thru the components contained on each page.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**
I want the search bar to filter whole components without using onClick buttons. It
needs to filter thru whole components with `onChange` the same way `.filter()` and onChange filters
thru an array list of text as the user types, and show only components that match keywords and hide the rest.

**Issues I'm trying to solve in my current code:**

1. The only way I can get whole components to filter, is to add and display them thru the SearchBar component itself,
   but needs to operate and filter thru whichever the current pages components are instead of
   using `<Block />` in the SearchBar component to display them. SearchBar should only filter whichever
   components are rendered on the current page. (Block was just used to test if it filters whole components)
2. The keywords in state of `compList:` will only work if they are the exact name of the component, but it
   needs to be triggered with generic keywords like `["taco", "burrito"]` etc. (somehow reference the keywords to
   the actual components maybe?)
3. For some reason, if the user backspaces, all of the components in the `<Block />` disappear. That
   doesn't need to happen..needs to display all components until a match is found. (somehow it's altering the states compList maybe?)

**SearchBar Component**

```
import React from 'react';
import './search-bar-styles.scss';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faSearch } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { BreakfastBurritoRecipe, BreakfastTacoRecipe } from './recipe-box';


export class SearchBar extends React.Component {
   
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            display: 'none',
            value: '',
            compList: ["BreakfastTacoRecipe", "BreakfastBurritoRecipe"]

        };
    
        this.showBar = this.showBar.bind(this);
        this.hideBar = this.hideBar.bind(this);
        this.userText = this.userText.bind(this);
    };


    showBar() {
        this.setState({ display: 'block' });
    };

    hideBar() {
        this.setState({ display: 'none', value: '' });
    };

    userText(event) {

        const newList = this.state.compList.filter(item => item.includes(this.state.value))
        this.setState({ value: event.target.value, compList: newList })        
    }


    render() {

        const _components = {
            BreakfastTacoRecipe,
            BreakfastBurritoRecipe
        }  

        return (
            <div>
                <div id="searchButtonContainer" /*name={this.userText}*/>
                    <div id="searchButton" onClick={this.showBar}>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearch} />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="searchContainer">
                    <div id="searchBox" style={{display: this.state.display}} onChange={this.showBar}>
                        <input value={this.state.value} onChange={this.userText} type="text" placeholder="Search.." />
                        <span id="closeSearchBtn" onClick={this.hideBar}>X</span>
                        <p>{this.state.value}</p>
                        <div>
                            {this.state.compList.map((component, index) => {
                            const Block = _components[component];
                            return <Block key={index} />
                        })}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
};
```

**Example of 1 of 5 pages where SearchBar will be rendered**

```
import React from 'react';
import './breakfast-styles.scss';
import { Header } from './header.js';
import { BreakfastTitleBox } from './breakfast-title-box.js';
import { BreakfastTacoRecipe } from './recipe-box.js';
import { BreakfastBurritoRecipe } from './recipe-box.js';
import { OmeletteRecipe } from './recipe-box.js';
import { BiscuitsNGravyRecipe } from './recipe-box.js';
import { SausageBreakfastRollRecipe } from './recipe-box.js';
import { Footer } from './footer.js';
import ScrollArrow  from './scrolltotop.js';
import { SearchBar } from './search-bar.js';


export class Breakfast extends React.Component {



    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ScrollArrow />
                <Header />
                <SearchBar />             <-----SearchBar being rendered on page
                <BreakfastTitleBox />
                <BreakfastTacoRecipe />   <----component to be filtered
                <BreakfastBurritoRecipe />    <----component to be filtered
                <OmeletteRecipe />            <----component to be filtered
                <BiscuitsNGravyRecipe  />     <----component to be filtered
                <SausageBreakfastRollRecipe /> <----component to be filtered
                <Footer />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Any suggestions? Examples?

Comment: Hey, so if I am understanding your question correctly. You want to render <BreafastTacoRecipe /> if a user searches say "taco". And you want to render <BreakfastBurritoRecipe /> when a user searches for say "burrito". Correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Also needs to contain other keywords for depending which page the user is currently on, if they are on the <Lunch /> page then "burger" would render <BurgerRecipe />. The idea is to use the same SearchBar component across all 5 pages and filter the recipe components in each page.

Comment: Have you heard of React Redux, or have you heard of some sort of global state management tool. I think you need a variable (you can called it query) that is accessible across all components. This way you can use an if statement inside each Recipe component to check if it should be rendered or not. Can show you an example if you would like.

Comment: Yes an example please. That makes sense...I've heard of Redux, but haven't used it yet.

Comment: Hey, so have you seen this? https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started. This is a simple React-Redux Example. Happy to chat more about it and guide you through how you can set it up for your project. But it might be easier to use some sort of chat room instead. I think the setup is quite heavy to be discussing here.

Comment: @cruise_lab late reply because I've spent a week reading thru the Redux docs, read thru a tutorial and it makes some sense, but I am still confused how to set it up for this particular project. Do I set the store, reducer, etc in the main index file or inside the <Breakfast /> component where <BreakfastTacoRecipe /> etc etc is rendered?

Comment: All good! In this instance, you would set it up in <Breakfast /> component. In general, you would want to set it at the root of your entire project.